# How to get lineItems.product option value

Tags: shopware6

I want to make a json field of an order to our API. The issue is, that it can't find productNumber.

I've made search of an order with the association:

```
    $this->context = $context;
    $criteria      = new Criteria([$orderId]);
    $criteria->addAssociation(OrderExtension::DSM_INTEGRATION_ORDER);
    $criteria->addAssociation('addresses');
    $criteria->addAssociation('billingAddress.country');
    $criteria->addAssociation('transactions.paymentMethod');
    $criteria->addAssociation('deliveries.shippingMethod');
    $criteria->addAssociation('deliveries.shippingOrderAddress.country');
    $criteria->addAssociation('lineItems.product');
    $criteria->addAssociation('lineItems.product.tags');
    $criteria->addAssociation('lineItems.product.options');
    $criteria->addAssociation('orderCustomer.customer');
    
    $result = $this->orderRepository->search($criteria, $context);
```

However, the result has no productNumber, when I receive the type "customized-products"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8nHs.png)

it use uses OrderEntity.

I want the productNumber, when the order is a type "customized-products". I expect, the association is something like "lineItems.product.customized_product", but I have yet to find the correct one.

Note. We use "productOswag_customized_products_templateptions"

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the product number starting from the order entity, via the order line items, you would have to proceed similar to this:

```php
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addAssociation('lineItems.product');

$result = $this->orderRepository->search($criteria, $context);
/** @var OrderEntity|null $order */
$order = $result->first();
/** @var OrderLineItemCollection|null $lineItems */
$lineItems = $order->getLineItems();
/** @var OrderLineItemEntity|null $lineItem */
$lineItem = $lineItems->first();
/** @var ProductEntity|null $product */
$product = $lineItem->getProduct();

$productNumber = $product->getProductNumber();
```

Note the getters might return `null` at any point, e.g. due to the product having been deleted in the meanwhile or the line item being a discount, so add some checks for that case.

Comment: with php 8.0 you can use the null safe operator 


```/** @var string|null $productNumber */
$productNumber = $result->first()?->getLineItems()?->first()?->getProduct()?->getProductNumber();
```